# solving the given differential equation $(1-x^2)y''+ 2xy' + ay = 0$ with $a$ a parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

As trainingsexercise for my course I have got to solve the following problem:

**the problem**

Given the differential equation $(1-x^2)y''+ 2xy' + ay = 0$ with $a$ a parameter.

a) give the powerseries solution of this differential equation around $x=0$

b) find $a$ so that at least one of the linear independent solutions is a polysome

c) There are 2 values for $a$ so that both solutions become polysomes. find these two values and the polysomes

**what I have tried so far**

a) bringing the differential equation into its standard form, $y'' + xP(x)y' + x^2Q(x)y =0$ and with $xP(x)$ and $x^2Q(x)$ differentiable in $x=0$, means that I can find two linear independent solutions without using *Frobenius-powerseries* thus: $$y_1(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n x^n}$$ and $$y_2(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n x^n}$$

I used then $y(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n x^n}$ and filled it in the differential equation. Then I changed the indices so that we get all $x$ to the same powers and came thus up with this:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2} x^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n(n+1)c_n x^n}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{nc_n x^n}+a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n x^n}=0$$

then I made a case distinction:

- $n=0$ : $2c_2+ac_0=0 \implies c_2 = \frac{-a}{2}c_0$
- $n\geq1$ : $(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2} - n(n-1)c_n+2nc_n +ac_n=0 \iff c_{n+2} = \frac{n(n-3)-a}{(n+2)(n+1)}c_n$

Now we have always steps by two, and we can creat two linear independent solution by having once $c_0=1,c_1=0$ and once $c_0=0,c_1=1$
Doing this brings me to the formulas:

- $n$ is even: $$c_{2k} = \frac{2 \cdot \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k-2j)(2k-3-2j)-a}{(2k+2)!}$$
- $n$ is odd: $$c_{2k+1} = \frac{6 \cdot \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k+1-2j)(2k-2-2j)-a}{(2k+3)!}$$

and then I get:  $$y_1(x)= 1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2 \cdot \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k-2j)(2k-3-2j)-a}{(2k+2)!}\cdot x^{2k}}$$
and $$y_2(x)= x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{6 \cdot \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2k+1-2j)(2k-2-2j)-a}{(2k+3)!}\cdot x^{2k+1}}$$

can anybody find my mistake?

for b) and c) I honestly don't know how I could solve this, any help would be very much appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: For comparison, WolframAlpha indicates that the solutions can be expressed in terms of associated Legendre functions of order 2 ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281-x%5E2%29y%27%27%2B+2xy%27+%2B+ay+%3D+0). In particular, if one writes $a:=(\nu+2)(\nu-1)$ then the solutions are $(x^2-1)P_{\nu}^2(x),(x^2-1)Q_{\nu}^2(x)$.

Comment: Cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Legendre's_differential_equation

Comment: thank you @Semiclassical for you correction and your provided link

Comment: Also, one way to make the recurrence look slightly prettier is to take the power series as $\sum_n C_n x^n/n!$. This gives $C_n=c_n\cdot n!$ and so obtains $C_{n+2} = (n(n-3)-a)C_n$. In other words, it entirely eliminates the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to distinguish between $n=0$ and $n \ge 1$: the recurrence $$c_{n+2} = -\frac{a+3n-n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} c_n$$ is true in both cases.

Hints for (b) and (c): Note that if $a + 3 n - n^2 = 0$, you'll get $c_{n+2k} = 0$ for all $k \ge 1$, and thus $y_1$ or $y_2$ (depending on whether $n$ is even or odd) is a polynomial.
For both $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be a polynomial, you'll want $a+3n-n^2$ to be $0$ for both an even $n$ and an odd $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply which helped me much further. So are my solutions for $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ not all that wrong?

Comment: for (b) and (c) wouldn't I then have to set myself on a specific $n$, thus the order of the polynomial?

Comment: If you look at the sequences of values of $3n - n^2$ for even $n$ and for odd $n$, you should find two that are in both sequences.